# Dotnet publish -framework parameter, when is it necessary / appropriate and what exactly does it do?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I've read the docs and I can't find a definitive answer that makes any sense.

What is the purpose of the -f (-framework) parameter in the .net 2.1 command `dotnet publish`

I did not use it before and only noticed it recently in an example on the Microsoft docs pages but following the docs does not clarify why it matters and the published result seems the same whether I use it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotnet publish` compiles the application, reads through its dependencies specified in the project file, and publishes the resulting set of files to a directory

The framework paramater is used to publish the project for a certain target framework (netstandard2.0, netcoreapp2.1, net472,...). Your application is compiled for that framework before it gets published to the specified folder.

The following command publishes a project in the current directory using the netcoreapp2.1 framework:

```
dotnet publish --framework netcoreapp2.1
```

You could also publish the app for the classic .net framework like this:

```
dotnet publish --framework net472
```

The framework parameter is optional and can be omitted. If not specified the framework is read from the project file.

Comment: Ahh..ok, your last sentence made it all clear to me, thank you.